UK TV show mid 80s-90s, about a group of brothers or extended family
It's a bit vague but I can remember watching a show as a kid, it was about a group of brothers or cousins each of which represented a different stereotype. I can remember one who was always scratching his name in to mugs etc, and was possibly a bin man.
The key element I remember was they each had their own territory or home that was important to them. One of the brothers home was a building site as he was some how the future brother and he'd been turned into a baby when he'd tried to enter the building site previously 

This is "Archer's Goon", a tv series made from the book by Diana Wynne Jones. (Disclaimer - the tv series was never shown in NZ and I have been unable to find a copy to buy, so I've only seen the first 10 minutes of the first episode! But I have read the book several times.)
A thug shows up in the Sykes' kitchen one day, demanding the 2000 Quentin owes Archer, and refuses to leave until he gets them. He scratches initials into a mug as a warning, and the family call him the Goon. Later he travels by rubbish truck.
The family - Quentin (father), Catriona (mother), Howard, Awful, and Fifi (boarder/au pair) - gradually find out about the 7 siblings who control the city. They are Dillian, Archer, Hathaway, Shine, Torquil, Erskine and Venturus, and they each control (or "farm") a different area of the city, eg police, rubbish, power. 
Venturus is the brother who tried to build a space ship but was sent back in time and became a baby again.

Oh my god that's it, I've been racking my brain over this for so long thank you so much

@user31403 If the answer is correct, please approve it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

@Walt Nope, I think OP has gone!
